# Loop character A/B alternately

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

How can I print A/B character alternately in python loop?

What I expect in result:

```
oneA
twoB
threeA
fourB
...
```

Comment: up until which value? if its just a couple you can type in the 'one', 'two' etc. otherwise we have to come up with a better plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeat through a sequence. This is typically used with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through a longer list, while repeating the shorter one. For example

```
import itertools
for i,j in zip(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], itertools.cycle('AB')):
    print(i+j)
```

Output

```
oneA
twoB
threeA
fourB
```

Comment: I used your solution. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139931/generate-sql-query-by-loop you can see whole code

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using the modulus operator % on the index of an incremented for loop for the numbers to alternate the letters:

```
list_num = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
list_alpha = ['A', 'B']
list_combined = []
for i in range(0, len(list_num)):
    list_combined.append(list_num[i] + (list_alpha[1] if i % 2 else list_alpha[0]))
list_combined
>>> ['oneA', 'twoB', 'threeA', 'fourB', 'fiveA', 'sixB']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
l1 = ['A','B']
l2 = ['one','two','three','four']
for i,val in enumerate(l2):
    print(val + l1[i%len(l1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
alternate_words = ['A', 'B']
    count = 0

while count < 5:
    print count+1, alternate_words[count % len(alternate_words)]
    count += 1
```

Output:

1 A

2 B

3 A

4 B

5 A

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help ->

```
a1 = ['A','B']
a2 = ['one','two','three','four']
for i in range(len(a2)):
    print a2[i]+a1[i%2]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the suggestion of @Graipher instead of using combined `zip()` with `itertools.cycle()`, better and simpler solution will be use `itertools.product()` which is

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
words = ['one', 'two', 'three'] 
for word, i in itertools.product(words, ('A', 'B')):
    print(word+i)
```